# Visio 2010: How to display name or documentation field of a final state object in a UML activity diagram

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010, uml

I have an UML activity diagram which includes a final state. This final state has a name which describe the state, but I am not able to show the name. Trying to add it as a Share Data hasn't worked since the field doesn't seem available. . An alternative to using name, is to use the documentation field.

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/150775/) show how this could be done in Visio 2003, but I have not found the functionality in Visio 2010.